# Append byte to a byte buffer in golang

Tags: go, byte

I have a message byte Buffer and I would like to append a byte at the end of the Buffer

I tried to append like this:

```
append(message.Buf, 0xff)
first argument to append must be slice; have *bytes.Buffer

append(0xff,message.Buf)
first argument to append must be slice; have untyped number
```

How can I make the 0xff as a slice to append?

Comment: The function `append` is for appending values to a slice and has **absolutely** **nothing** to do with bytes.Buffer which is not a slice. Just Write to your bytes.Buffer. And please read the docs ,especially https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteByte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a buffer which is of type [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) (or more specifically a pointer to that type). It has a [`Buffer.WriteByte()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteByte) method, just use that:

```
message.Buf.WriteByte(0xff)
```

The builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function which you tried to call is to append values to [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types). `bytes.Buffer` is not a slice, you can't use that with `append()` (it is implemented using an internal slice, but that is an implementation detail which you should not build on / utilize).